# Java - How to return Int[] from class method

Tags: java, class, methods, insert

I have a problem, in the test of my program that I have to do as homework , theres write `List3 MyClass = List2.reverse()` List2 is a list as an array , I want to create a new list (List3) using my class (MyClass) as the List2 reversed, I did the reverse but in my method if I write `Public MyClass reverse() :`I cannot return a list , he says to me that I have to put `Public int[] reverse()` for return list but if I do in the Tester says that `List3 MyClass = List2.reverse()` cannot work because the class called is int[] type and not Class type.

```
public MyList reverse_new()
{
    int[] l = new int[t.length];
    int lunghezzo = t.length - 1;
    for(int x = 0 ; x < t.length ; x++)
    {
        l[x] = t[lunghezzo - x];
    }


    return l;
}
```

here he says that I have to put int [] for return a list so then I do :

```
public int[] reverse_new()
{
    int[] l = new int[t.length];
    int lunghezzo = t.length - 1;
    for(int x = 0 ; x < t.length ; x++)
    {
        l[x] = t[lunghezzo - x];
    }


    return l;
}
```

but the tester says that theres an error when I do :

```
public class TestList {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numeri = {
            100, 200, 300
    };

    MyList L1 = new MyList();
    MyList L2 = new MyList(numeri);
    MyList L3 = L2.reverse_new();
```

P.S. I cannot change the Tester is from my teacher. and I can use only method created by myself.

Comment: This code is really hard to follow because it's not actually Java code. Can you make it as such?

Comment: sorry , how do I do?

Comment: That's considerably better and illustrates what you're trying to do much more specifically.

Comment: Is `reverse_new` defined inside of a class or on its own?

Comment: inside of MyClass , the name of the class is MyClass

Comment: If you're expecting `int[]` as a return value then why are you assigning that to `MyList L3`? It's possible that you're supposed to be returning a new instance of that class with the *contents* reversed, not the raw reversed contents.

Comment: if I put MyClass L3 = L2; he does but if I extend with .reverse he doesn't do it how can I fix it?

Comment: As far as I can tell you're supposed to return a new instance of `MyList` with the contents reversed.

Comment: yes I know you right but I cannot change the tester I have to assign to L3 this value , my question is how I can change my class for do this.

how I can return this new instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your code, parts are missing, but this should cover the reverse case:

```
public MyList reverse_new()
{
    int[] l = new int[t.length];
    int lunghezzo = t.length - 1;
    for(int x = 0 ; x < t.length ; x++)
    {
        l[x] = t[lunghezzo - x];
    }

    return new MyList(l);
}
```

Where in this case you wrap that reversed list back inside a MyList object.

Comment: u are the best nice it works , last question , how can I say to my class that if from the tester I do : "L2.method1.method2" ?  if I do L2.method it works of course but if I put the second method in line he says error.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: I mean if I want to do L2.reverse().reverse() he should reverse 2 times but I cannot do it cause he give me  back an error .

Comment: That's a separate question, so with your updated code I'd suggest opening a new one and we can address that there.